# How to use in_array() for caseless?

Tags: php

It's a big array, so i won't to strtolower every value.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason to avoid strtolower 'on a big array' or you're just looking for alternative options? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`preg_grep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with the case insensitivity flag “`i`”:

```
$result = preg_grep('/pattern/i', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the [`strcasecmp` function](http://docs.php.net/strcasecmp):

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
$needle = 'FOO';

$hit = false;
foreach ($array as $elem) {
    if (is_string($elem) && strcasecmp($needle, $elem) == 0) {
        $hit = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($hit);
```

Comment: This is the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is only the way with strtolower. See also the comment in the PHP doc: http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#88554

Edit:
As you can see in the comment, there is **of course** more than one way to solve it. I probably miss spelled what I tried to say ;-). Sorry.

Comment: That's a surprising answer, given that two different answers (not using `strotolower`) have already been posted.

Comment: I was just too slow. And to be honest, there are always a lot ways to solve a problem. And I don't see any reason to use strcasecmp or preg_grep wit the i-Flag... For me each of the answers solve the problem...